# jQuery event delegation with non-trivial HTML markup?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two DIVs, first one has a link in it that contains the id of the second DIV in its HREF attribute ([complete setup on jsbin](http://jsbin.com/azimo/edit)).

I want to animate the second DIV when user clicks on the first - anywhere on the first. I also want to use event delegation because I'll have many such "DIV couples" on a page (and I'm using a JS snippet from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663842/jquery-unbinding-events-speed-increases/663886#663886)).

If user clicks on the DIV itself, it will work - just check firebug console output. The problem is, if user clicks on one of the SPANs or the link itself, it doesn't work anymore.

How can I generalize the click handler to manage clicks on anything inside my DIV?

Here's the JS:

```
$('#a').click(function(e) { 
    var n = $(e.target)[0]; 
    console.log(n); 

    if ( n && (n.nodeName.toUpperCase() == 'DIV') ) { 
        var id = $(n).find('a').attr('hash'); 

        console.log(id); 
        $(id).slideToggle(); 
    } 
    return false; 
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me so long to write up the question that I decided to post it anyway, perhaps someone suggests a better way.

Here's the solution I found ([jsbin sandbox](http://jsbin.com/iyamo)):

```
$('#a').click(function(e) {
    var n = $(e.target)[0];

    var name = n.nodeName.toLowerCase() + '.' + n.className.toLowerCase();

    if (n && (name === "div.clicker" || $(n).parents("div.clicker").length )) {
        var id = $(n).find('a').attr('hash');
        if(!id) {
            id = $(n).parents("div.clicker").find('a').attr('hash');
        }
        console.log(id);
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution.  Not sure if that's exactly what you wanted, but it works for me.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#a').click(function() {
        var a = $("a", this);
        $(a[0].hash).slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Edit: Tested in both IE7 and Fx3

---

Edit: In that case...

```
$(function() {
    $("a.tab").click(function() {
        $($(this).attr("hash")).slideToggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Something like that might work (putting the tab class on anything that has a div "attached" to it).  However, I'm not sure unless I actually see an example of it.  Although if you want  it to work when clicking on the span...you would attach the class to the span, and instead do:

```
$(function() {
    $("span.tab").click(function() {
        var a = $("a",this);
        $(a.attr("hash")).slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Not sure if you want an open div to close if another one is opened.  If this doesn't solve your problem, it would help if you would put up an example on jsbin...

Comment: This definitely looks simpler!

Comment: Actually, now that I had a chance to actually test it, it won't work, because I have multiple links inside the DIV, that's the whole point about event delegation. Didn't really think when I saw this and accepted it as the correct answer.

Comment: So, basically there will be multiple links in div#a, however there is just one that has the id of the other div in it?  And when you click anywhere in the div#a you want the div referred to by that link animated?  Or will there be multiple links, and each one you want to animate a different other div?  In the first case, add a class to the link with the hash in it, for instance info, and change $("a",this) to $("a.info",this)

Comment: Yes, the latter: many link-DIV couples, and each link animates the DIV which whose ID inside the link's HREF attribute (that's why I have it in the first place, to create that connection between a link and a DIV). Even if I add a class to each link, this will grab ALL the links inside the container, which has multiple link-DIV couples.